# Try to call a function from data from a dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to call a function from a selection from a drop down.. Just basic functions making changes to a image.. I was told to do it from a passing data to a function.. but i couldnt figure out to get it working so I tried to use a if. not sure wats wrong?? im new to the language

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Functions</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function myfunction(){
    var selection = document.getElementById('changes');
    var a = dropdown1.selectedIndex;
}

if (a==0){
    moveimage();
}
else if (a==1){
    makeinvisible();
}
else if (a==2){
    makelarger();
}
else if (a==3){
    makesmaller();
}


function moveimage(){
    var x = document.getElementById('image');
    x.style.marginTop="50px";
}

function makeinvisible(){
    var x = document.getElementById('image');
    x.style.visibility="hidden";
}

function makelarger(){
    var x = document.getElementById('image');
    image.width="1000";
    image.height="1000";
}

function makesmaller(){
    var x = document.getElementById('image');
    image.width="100";
    image.height="100";
}

</script>

<form name="change">
    <img src = "cookie.jpg" id="image">
</br>
<select id="changes">
    <option value="0" >Larger</option>
    <option value="1">Smaller</option>
    <option value="2">Move</option>
    <option value="3">Invisible</option>
</select>
</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>

<input type=button value="Adjust Image" onchange="myfunction()">

</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I noticed you don't have a closing `</form>` tag

Answer (score 2):

First, you have an error (as already noted by Naveen) in your placement of `}`, which removes your `if`/`else` block from your function (causing an error, because `a` is then `undefined` at the point at which this block is evaluated.

Further, the HTML of your button, in which you assign the event-handler:

```
<input type=button value="Adjust Image" onchange="myfunction()">
```

an `input` of `type="button"` has no `onchange`/`change` event; though it does have a `click`/`onclick`:

```
<input type=button value="Adjust Image" onclick="myfunction()">
```

Then, you seem to have to have muddled the places in which you call your functions:

```
Select Shows:    |    selectedIndex is: | You call:        | Should (probably) call:
-----------------+----------------------+------------------+-------------------------
Larger           |    0                 | moveImage()      |  makeLarger()
Smaller          |    1                 | makeinvisible()  |  makesmaller()
Move             |    2                 | makelarger()     |  moveimage()
Invisible        |    3                 | makesmaller()    |  makeinvisible()
```

After that, you're trying to adjust the sizes (in `makesmaller()` and `makelarger()`), using properties of the Node itself: `image.height` and `image.width`. These aren't properties of the image, but of the `style` properties of the image, and should be:

```
image.style.width = '1000';
image.style.height = '1000';
```

Of course, these property-values require a unit, so you need to add `px` as well:

```
image.style.width = '1000px';
image.style.height = '1000px';
```

Giving:

```
function myfunction() {
    var selection = document.getElementById('changes');
    var a = selection.selectedIndex;
    if (a === 0) {
        makelarger();
    } else if (a == 1) {
        makesmaller();
    } else if (a == 2) {
        moveimage();
    } else if (a == 3) {
        makeinvisible();
    }
}


function moveimage() {
    var x = document.getElementById('image');
    x.style.marginTop = "50px";
}

function makeinvisible() {
    var x = document.getElementById('image');
    x.style.visibility = "hidden";
}

function makelarger() {
    var x = document.getElementById('image');
    image.style.width = "1000px";
    image.style.height = "1000px";
}

function makesmaller() {
    var x = document.getElementById('image');
    image.style.width = "100px";
    image.style.height = "100px";
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UYyMh/).

Now, to the improvements.

The `if`/`else` is unnecessarily expensive, you're re-evaluating the same variable multiple times. To save time, use a `switch() {...}` instead, which evaluates the variable once:

```
switch (a) {
    case 0:
        makelarger();
        break;
    case 1:
        makesmaller();
        break;
    case 2:
        moveimage();
        break;
    case 3:
        makeinvisible();
        break;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UYyMh/1/).

With the `switch` *every* case will be checked (including those *after* the first matching case), so the `break` is important, in order to force subsequent checks to be skipped, and for the `switch` to be exited.

There is also no need to create two variables prior to the switch (especially since you're not using them afterwards), so you might as well, instead, simply do:

```
function myfunction() {
    switch (document.getElementById('changes').selectedIndex) {
        case 0:
            makelarger();
            break;
        case 1:
            makesmaller();
            break;
        case 2:
            moveimage();
            break;
        case 3:
            makeinvisible();
            break;
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UYyMh/2/).

Also, the in-line event-handler (attempting to use `onchange` and subsequently using `onclick` in my update) is poor-practice, since it leads to 'obtrusive JavaScript', which is difficult to maintain, so we're moving the event-handler into the JavaScript itself, after giving the relevant element an `id` (by which to easily target it):

```
<input id="buttonElem" type=button value="Adjust Image" />

document.getElementById('buttonElem').addEventListener('click', myfunction);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UYyMh/4/).

Because `addEventListener()` isn't well supported in IE until, I think, version 10, you might, however, prefer to use instead (with the same `id` on the `input`):

```
document.getElementById('buttonElem').onclick = myfunction;
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UYyMh/5/).

You could also, of course, rather than maintain a `switch` of appropriate indices-to-functions use a map of those indices and functions:

```
var funcMap = {
    0 : makelarger,
    1 : makesmaller,
    2 : moveimage,
    3 : makeinvisible
};

    function myfunction() {
        var select = document.getElementById('changes');
        funcMap[select.selectedIndex]();
    }
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UYyMh/6/).

This, potentially, allows you to pass in different objects to the function which allows multiple elements to call the same function and have different secondary functions called according to the map passed in (in this case it's of limited use, though, since you've only the one `select` element calling that function; but for future use it's worth remembering).

It is, however, better to ensure that there is a function to be called, or a property in that map, related to the key we're using; so we can adapt the prior JavaScript to:

```
    function myfunction() {
        var select = document.getElementById('changes');
        if (funcMap.hasOwnProperty(select.selectedIndex)) {
            funcMap[select.selectedIndex]();
        }
    }
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UYyMh/7/).

At this point, of course, we're repeating an earlier mistake and re-evaluating the same thing twice (`select.selectedIndex`), so instead:

```
function myfunction() {
    var selected = document.getElementById('changes').selectedIndex;
    if (funcMap.hasOwnProperty(selected)){
        funcMap[selected]();
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UYyMh/8/).

Comment: This a really nice answer, did you used anything to generate that ASCII table?

Comment: Thank you very much! And no, the ASCII table was created purely through careful use of the space, `-`, `+` and `|` characters. Not hard to do, though. Thankfully... :)

Answer (score 1):

you have misplaced closed right curly brace `}` of `myfunction()`

```
function myfunction()
{
   var selection = document.getElementById('changes');
   var a = dropdown1.selectedIndex;
   if (a ==0)
   {
     moveimage();
   }

   else if (a ==1)
   {
     makeinvisible();
   }

   else if (a ==2)
  {
    makelarger();
  }
  else if (a ==3)
  {
    makesmaller();
  }
}

function moveimage()
{
    var x = document.getElementById('image');
    x.style.marginTop="50px";
}
function makeinvisible()
{
    var x = document.getElementById('image');
    x.style.visibility="hidden";
}
function makelarger()
{
    var x = document.getElementById('image');
    image.width="1000px";
    image.height="1000px"
}
function makesmaller()
{
    var x = document.getElementById('image');
    image.width="100px";
    image.height="100px"
}
```

Comment: Thanks but still not working. there more errors in it..i think

Comment: @Francis: out of curiosity, how're things working with my answer? Anything positive at all?

Comment: @DavidThomas Sorry not being here for a while. Your help was very useful thanks